# Deleting extra spaces with sed

Tags: sed

I have a function that looks like this:

```
myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3" );
```

Note the extra space at the end. I'm trying to delete that extra space with sed. Right now, I'm just testing it with `echo` rather than doing it on the real file. My command is

```
echo 'myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3" );' | sed 's/myfunc\(.* \);/myfunc\(.*\);/g'
```

But when I run it, it simply outputs the original text, with no change (including that extra space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo 'myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3" );' | sed 's/^\(.*\) /\1/g'
myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
```

**Explanation:**

- `^\(.*\)` Captures all the chars from the starting upto last space character.(excluding the last space character). (*I included the space character in the pattern but it failed to display.*)
- In the replacement part, all the matched characters are replaced by the characters within the first captured group .

OR

```
$ echo 'myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"  );' | sed -E 's/(myfunc\(.*[^ ]) +(\))/\1\2/g'
myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
```

Comment: Could you explain how this gets the space? It works but I don't get how. It looks as though you're not looking for any extra spaces, since the right parenthesis follows the star.

Comment: this code removes the last space in the given line, no matter where it is, right? E.g. `fun("a", "b", "c")` -> `fun("a", "b","c")` and `fun("a", "b", "c" ) ;` -> `fun("a", "b", "c" );`

Comment: @Kent i posted according to the op's input.

Comment: Thanks for updating your description - I'm starting to understand this. I edited your answer a little bit to use extended REs and made it so that it can capture all extra spaces, and only in the parenthesized part. Feel free to add it to your answer: `echo 'myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"  );' | sed -E 's/(.*[^ ]) +(.*)/\1\2/g'`

Comment: Oops - one little change to make it work in a more general setting: `sed -E 's/(myfunc\(.*[^ ]) +(\))/\1\2/g'` That way it can actually be used on files. Otherwise, it picks up all kinds of spaces and tries to delete them. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
echo 'myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3" );' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\})/)/'
```

It removes one or more spaces before a closing parenthesis. I'm not sure what version of sed you're using but that should work on any of them.

Output:

```
myfunc("arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
```